# How to capture only two types of packets using Wireshark

Tags: wireshark

When I enable Wireshark capture on my laptop, the application becomes slow because it captures all the packets. I am running about 100 Mbps of traffic with different packet sizes.

Let's say, I only need to capture rtp,sip packets and ignore the other UDP, TCP, DHCP etc. 
How can I do it using Wireshark?

Note: I know the filter option to view only the packets I need, but the request is to only capture rtp packets

Answer (score 0):

From the [Wireshark SIP wiki page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SIP):

---

**Capture Filter**

You cannot directly filter SIP protocols while capturing. However, if you know the [UDP](https://wiki.wireshark.org/UDP) or [TCP](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP) or port used (see above), you can filter on that one.

---

For help with writing capture filters, refer to the [pcap-filter man page](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html).

Comment: Thanks.If I am using the capture filter 'host <ip4 add>' I am able to capture only packets that are destined for that IP and all other packets are ignored.